# Django webhooks

Tags: django, webhooks, httpresponse

Need help in creating and understanding webhooks in Django.From where should I start ? How should I get to learn to implement a simple webhook in which I pass 2,3 parameters like id and name and it should get printed through the URL into the view without any third party or package.

Comment: See the documentation, and please tell us what you don't understand. Here is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webhooks is nothing special, it is just an URL endpoint, you can define the format of the request and the response. The most common format now is JSON in both the request and response.

here is a simple webhook

```
def run(request):
    import json
    req = json.loads(request.body)
    ..... # do your function
    return  JsonResponse({"message":"Received Succesfully")
```

Comment: I got about webhooks but what to know its detailed implementations and uses